# iOS: Main function

Tags: ios

Could someone give some explanation what is the main function exactly does in iOS app? and who is calling this function and inputting the right parameter?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main()` is the main entry point for any C, C++, or Objective-C program. It's basically called by the operating system to start the program. (That's not quite true -- it's a little more complicated than that, but it's not a bad mental model.) in fact, `main` doesn't just start the program -- it *is* the program. The program ends when execution reaches the end of `main`.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to mainly know, what are these arguments int argc, char *argv[] given by OS? Any Idea, please share.

Comment: They're the arguments to the program. `argc` is the number of arguments, and `argv` is a list of the arguments. You can learn more about them in any C reference. You generally don't have to worry about them at all when you're writing iOS apps.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the main function exactly doing?

It merely calls the `UIApplicationMain()` function which essentially creates the app delegate (from the class specified as its 4th argument) and sets up the main run loop of the application.

> Who is calling this function and inputting the right parameter?

iOS.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS runtime, it loads before main() is called, so there must be a higher level controller acts as a REAL MAIN()